# Symfony3 ldap component

Tags: php, ldap, symfony

I am trying authenticate a user through a LDAP and fetch authenticated user object. To do so I am using Symfony3 installed its [ldap](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/ldap.html) component.

To install the ldap component I used composer like so:

```
composer require symfony/ldap
```

Just to test things around I am using this free test [AD](http://www.forumsys.com/en/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/). 
So now I am in a position where the component works and I can extend its class.

Looking at the component usage docs first thing is to connect to AD:

```
$ldap = new LdapClient('ldap.forumsys.com', 389, 3, false, true);
```

When I `var_dump($ldap)` this is what i get:

```
object(Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient)#359 (1) {
object(Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap)#360 (1) {
object(Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter)#361 (3) {
array(6) {
      ["host"] "ldap.forumsys.com"
      ["port"] 389
      ["version"] 3
      ["useSsl"] false
      ["useStartTls"] true
      ["optReferrals"] false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second step is to authenticate above connection using DN and user password:

```
$ldap->bind('ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com', 'password');
```

the DN acording to the ldap.forumsys.com is:

```
 -> cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com

 ||

 -> ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com
```

am not sure but recon is the second one either way I tried both also the password for each user is password.

This is when symfony throws this error:

```
    The options "optReferrals", "useSsl", "useStartTls" do not exist. Defined 

options are: "connection_string", "debug", "encryption", "host", "options", 

"port", "referrals", "version".
```

Do not understand much from it and not sure why it does not work.

I have also found this doc:

```
[Symf Ldap Doc][3]
```

Does this two docs show how connect together if so how to link them...?

Comment: This question popped up to me after I got the same error when trying to use `useSsl=true` option with the  `LdapAdapter` class directly.

While `LdapAdapter` is obviously mismatching the docs - `"encryption"` option caught my attention, so I'm now setting `encryption=ssl` in order to have a secure connection. It appears that `encrytpion=tls` is also possible.

I hope someone else finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

bind should be like this:

```
$ldap->bind('cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com', 'password');
```

second edit below.

I was mistaken, I think you need to call like this:

```
$ldap = new LdapClient('ldap.forumsys.com', 389, 3, false, false, false);
```

If you need a reference for using FR3DLdapBundle instead, take a [look at my blog](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/symfony-ad-integration/) on what I did to set that up.

Comment: hey thx for your answer like I mentioned I have tried both and the result is the same in both cases

Comment: Got that information from this [Symfony API LdapClient link](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Ldap/LdapClient.html). Although it concerns me that it is deprecated.

Comment: hey I tried it it did not work either :/ I am just wondering is there anything out there I can use to make ldap calls with symfony3 ?

Comment: Hi Tomazi. I use the FR3DLdapBundle and it works with that test server you show (ldap.forumsys.com) in your post above. Also now I have it working with MS Active Directory - and it works well. This is the first time I heard about this Symfony Ldap component. There is also a [YML config](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-ldap-component) shown here.

Comment: hmmm so u didn not use symfony/ldap bundle? u used FR3DLdapBundle with the given YML config. if so could you share the code and steps you took to get this working.

Comment: @Tomazi I updated my post to include a link to my blog called "Smyfony AD Integration". In that blog I show the YAML file I used to get things working. I also updated it to show what I used to get AD working as well.